# Rotating links when submit button is clicked

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink, rotation, submit-button

I want to know if there is a way to have the submit button in a form redirect to different links every time its clicked depending on what the person selected. For example: my form would have name, email, and how did you hear about us with a drop down of numerous options and a submit button. So if the person picked option 1 then once the submit button is clicked it would redirect to link 1. When another person comes and pick option 1 also it would then redirect to link 2. When another person comes and pick option 1 again it will redirect to link 1 and so on. This would need to be possible for all options in the drop down and email addresses would be recorded for me to see at a later time. Is this possible? Sorry i am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this

**HTML**

```
<form action="./hi_friend.php" method="post"  id="countForm">
<select name="selList" id="selList">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Last</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#countForm').submit(function(){
  var $form = $("#countForm");

  if($("#selList").val() == "1")
    $form.action = "./first_result.php";
  else if($("#selList").val() == "2")
    $form.action = "./second_result.php";
  else if($("#selList").val() == "3")
    $form.action = "./last_result.php";

  alert("submit to " + $form.action);
  return true;
});
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byqbf9n7/)**

Comment: Im sorry Im new to this. where would I put this code?

Comment: @kmoore1004 You need [jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery). copy 1.x snippet code and paste into between `head`. and copy(and edit) js code of my answer, paste into between `<script>` and `</script>`.